# Node Array / Object Iteration

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have below array which I converted into Object but what I need is only a few of key/value pairs.  For that, I am looking for creating an object with required keys only.

For example:

Final result only include
  1 - Start
  2 - UserId, 
  3 - Duration

```
for (var counter = 0; counter < rows.length; counter++) {
  newObj[counter].Start = oldObj[counter].starttime;
  newObj[counter].UseId = oldObj[counter].card_id;
  newObj[counter].Duration = oldObj[counter].sessiontime;
}

[
  {
    "id": 52,
    "sessionid": "SIP/7631253675-0003e946",
    "uniqueid": "1498843959.256441",
    "card_id": 1,
    "nasipaddress": "",
    "starttime": "2017-06-30T16:32:58.000Z",
    "stoptime": "2017-06-30T16:33:07.000Z",
    "sessiontime": 9,
    "calledstation": "447454411749",
    "sessionbill": 1.5,
    "id_tariffgroup": 1,
    "id_tariffplan": 1,
    "id_ratecard": 2,
    "id_trunk": 2,
    "sipiax": 0,
    "src": "2638645541115",
    "id_did": null,
    "buycost": 0.05,
    "id_card_package_offer": null,
    "real_sessiontime": 9,
    "dnid": "0044745881749",
    "terminatecauseid": 1,
    "destination": 44,
    "a2b_custom1": "",
    "a2b_custom2": ""
},
{
    "id": 53,
    "sessionid": "SIP/7631253675-0003e949",
    "uniqueid": "1498844032.256444",
    "card_id": 1,
    "nasipaddress": "",
    "starttime": "2017-06-30T16:34:16.000Z",
    "stoptime": "2017-06-30T16:34:21.000Z",
    "sessiontime": 5,
    "calledstation": "447438811813",
    "sessionbill": 1.5,
    "id_tariffgroup": 1,
    "id_tariffplan": 1,
    "id_ratecard": 2,
    "id_trunk": 2,
    "sipiax": 0,
    "src": "2638644991115",
    "id_did": null,
    "buycost": 0.05,
    "id_card_package_offer": null,
    "real_sessiontime": 5,
    "dnid": "00447466811813",
    "terminatecauseid": 1,
    "destination": 44,
    "a2b_custom1": "",
    "a2b_custom2": ""
  }
]
```

Could you please help me to solve? Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array#map` and create your object while iterating over your original object array and extracting out the values from each object.

```js
var data = [{ "id": 52, "sessionid": "SIP/7631253675-0003e946", "uniqueid": "1498843959.256441", "card_id": 1, "nasipaddress": "", "starttime": "2017-06-30T16:32:58.000Z", "stoptime": "2017-06-30T16:33:07.000Z", "sessiontime": 9, "calledstation": "447454411749","sessionbill": 1.5, "id_tariffgroup": 1, "id_tariffplan": 1, "id_ratecard": 2, "id_trunk": 2, "sipiax": 0, "src": "2638645541115", "id_did": null, "buycost": 0.05, "id_card_package_offer": null, "real_sessiontime": 9, "dnid": "0044745881749", "terminatecauseid":1, "destination": 44, "a2b_custom1": "", "a2b_custom2": "" }, { "id": 53, "sessionid": "SIP/7631253675-0003e949", "uniqueid": "1498844032.256444", "card_id": 1, "nasipaddress": "", "starttime": "2017-06-30T16:34:16.000Z", "stoptime": "2017-06-30T16:34:21.000Z","sessiontime": 5, "calledstation": "447438811813", "sessionbill": 1.5, "id_tariffgroup": 1, "id_tariffplan": 1, "id_ratecard": 2, "id_trunk": 2, "sipiax": 0, "src": "2638644991115", "id_did": null, "buycost": 0.05, "id_card_package_offer": null, "real_sessiontime":5, "dnid": "00447466811813", "terminatecauseid": 1, "destination": 44, "a2b_custom1": "", "a2b_custom2": "" } ],
  result = data.map(o => ({Start: o.starttime, UseId: o.card_id, Duration: o.sessiontime}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code will give you an error. You are trying to a access nth element of newObj array, which is not yet inititalised.

You can write the code as

```
for (var counter = 0; counter < rows.length; counter++) {
   newObj.push({});
   newObj[counter].Start = oldObj[counter].starttime;
   newObj[counter].UseId = oldObj[counter].card_id;
   newObj[counter].Duration = oldObj[counter].sessiontime;
}
```